# how to avoid generation document.write in GWT cache.js file

Tags: javascript, gwt, client-side

I am using Gwt 2.4. After compiling my project i am getting some document.write lines in the `mymodle.chache.js` which is most weired .

So i want to know the places which producing these lines in my GWT code  and came across and found some lines of code like

`element.setInnerHtml("blah ..blah..")`;

and

`doc.write("blah..blah ..")`;

So i removed those line of code and compiled again again and still getting some `(ex:document.write(df+er+t))` lines .

Anyone suggest  a way to find the cause to producing those lines from my GWT ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(assuming you're talking about the `*.nocache.js` file rather than the `*.cache.*` files, as `*.cache.*` don't contain calls to `document.write`, unless you're using a crappy third-party lib)

The `*.nocache.js` file is generated by the primary linker, so its content is independent from your code. It contains calls to `document.write()` for various things: determine your *module base URL* (as a last resort, when it cannot infer it from elsewhere), inject scripts and stylesheets referenced from your `*.gwt.xml` files, and finally inject the GWT application code itself (with the standard linker, this will be an `<iframe>`, with the newer `xsiframe` linker it'll be a `<script>`).
If you're really worried about it, it can be customized quite easily by extending the `CrossSiteIframeLinker` (`xsiframe` linker) and providing different code snippets.

Tip: compile with `-style PRETTY` to make the generated code readable.

Comment: I searched about CrossSiteIframeLinker but didn't get proper example to integrate in our project. do you have any example or link which help me?

Comment: No sorry, it's completely undocumented. Have a look at the code, and the `*.js` snippets in `com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.impl`, and replace the ones that contain `document.write` with your own by overriding the appropriate methods of `CrossSiteIframeLinker`; and finally, just like any linker, use `<declare-linker>` and `<add-linker>` in your `*.gwt.xml` to use your extended linker.

Comment: is it mandatory to use linker for internal js sources which are included in gwt.xml. for example I am using ckediter in my project and added jars in build path. so can I treat it as external source or only sources like [HTTP] treat as external sources.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Can we change *.js  files in com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.impl? I mean it is a gwt lib file right.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to hand-edit/modify mymodle.cache.js. This file gets generated again from GWT Compiler. What issue are you trying to solve by hand-editing it?

Comment: we are not editing the cache file ..we are trying to modify our GWT code to avoid those lines in generated chache file ..

Comment: Can you specify what you are trying to avoid in those lines w.r.t GWT code. Note: Not all lines of code in cache.html are understandable  and are there as GWT bootscript. They do not map to your widget code.

Comment: We are working on some STQC related works. Pl. refer to https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet for secure development of client-side code. So In our project, We have to find out some cases which is responsible to generate security thread.

Comment: Did you refer the security sections under https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuide